# Why deleted items still appear in AWS Datastore

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a backend in AWS Amplify where my data is stored. Upon querying a model and then deleting an item of the model directly from Content in Amplify Studio, I still get the same number of items. After checking their content I found out the difference is that for existing items the property `_deleted` holds the value `null` and the items that have actually been deleted hold the value `undefined`.
Why is that ? and is there a way to deleted items and make them completely disappear from the datastore ?

Answer (score 0):

`DataStore.query` always operates on local data, not server data--it relies on the automatically managed subscriptions to keep the local store consistent.

If you want a deleted item to be reflected in your UI immediately, i've been using `DataStore.observeQuery()` seen in the documentation linked below for real time data subscriptions:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/real-time/q/platform/js/

Answer (score 0):

DataStore.observeQuery() also give the local store data not server side data when i syncing data in online mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when working on a project which had multi frontend some uses Datastore and some not, so I made lambda function to clean any deleted records from the tables, if you prefer this approach follow these steps:

**1-**  Go to AWS console and create new lambda function ‘DeleteItemsForDatastore’

**2-**  Go to function configuration under the execution role click on **Role name link** this will redirect you to the role page click on **add permissions** and select **attach policies** and search for `'AWSLmbdaInvocation-DynamoDB'` and add it, and again click **Add Permissions** select **Create inline policy** and search for `DynamoDB` and on **write** section select `'DeleteItem'` and add it.

**3-**  Now update your lambda code

```
import { DynamoDBClient, DeleteItemCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb'

export const handler = async (event) => {
  
  const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: 'us-east-1' })
  
 console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`)
 
  for (const record of event.Records) {
      console.log('Data---> ', record.dynamodb)
      const tableName = record.eventSourceARN.split('/')[1] 
       const params = {
          TableName: tableName,
          Key: record.dynamodb.Keys,
        }
        
        const command = new DeleteItemCommand(params)
        const r = await client.send(command)
        console.log('response--> ', r)
  }
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Items Deleted Successfuly!'),
  };
  return response;
};
```

and deploy, this code will delete any records in the event but don’t worry we will add filter in next step.

**4-**  Go to lambda **configuration** on **triggers** click **add trigger** and search for `DynamoDB` and select your table name form the list and change **Batch size** to 1, and down on **additional settings** click add on **filter criteria** and past this criteria

```
{ "dynamodb": { "NewImage": { "_ttl": { "N": [ { "exists": true } ] } } } }
```

now only when the record have _ttl (which only exist on deleted items) the function will invoke this will reduce invoking cost, now you can add triggers to all tables that you want to clear

Hope this will help.